# program is working fine but eclipse is showing warning for textview

Tags: android

i would like to know why eclipse is showing warning "[I18N] Hardcoded string "TextView", should use @string resource" in the xml code below .Actually i am trying to get the text written by user in an edit Text in an activity to this current activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is unclear about this warning? It is considered good practise to keep all your hardcoded strings in one place (as resource), so Eclipse warns you that you didn't. Don't bother to much, it's just a warning. Alternatively, you could just remove the line that causes the warning, since you don't use the hardcoded value anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says, you are using a "hard-coded" string which is less efficient than using the `String resource`. Simply remove

```
android:text="TextView"
```

if you don't want the warning to show. If you want it there then disregard the warning or add it to the `String resource` file. The `Text` property isn't needed. If you are expecting user input then you should change it to an `EditText` anyway unless you have a reason for using `TextView`

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.01" />
```

Then if you want it to display something such as "Enter input here" in the `View` then you can add `android:hint"Text to display"`. But this will give you the same warning if you don't add it to the `strings.xml` and use `android:hint="@string/nameInStringsFile"`.

But these warnings are just that. Suggesting possibly more efficient methods or ways of implementing whatever you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you are receiving a warning, is due to the fact that you are trying to hardcode a string which is not good convention in Android programming due to possible redundancy:

```
    <TextView
        ...
        android:text="TextView" />
```

You should rather create a reference to a string in the .../res/values/strings.xml file like so:

```
    <TextView
        ...
        android:text="@string/TextView" />
```

.. and define it in your strings.xml file:

```
<string name="TextView">TextView</string>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change the XML to the following to remove the warning

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.01" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

The reason you are seeing the warning is because you had set the text to "TextView" inside the XML layout file. It is Android best practice to put all Strings inside the strings.xml file in your res/values folder which creates [string resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html). One you have a string in a resource file you can reference it from your layout file using the syntax "@string/string_name".